# Java: Use OR operator with .endsWith

Tags: java, string

I have bunch of strings I want to separate them using `.endsWith` function. I want to write something like this:

```
if (textString.endsWith("_xyz"))
   //do this
else if (textString.endsWith("_xyz" || "_pqr" || "_abc")) 
   throw new Error();
```

Is it possible using `.endsWith` if not is there another optimal way to achieve above requirement?

Comment: `else if ( textString.endsWith("_xyz") || textString.endsWith("_pqr") || textString.endsWith("_abc"))`

Comment: This should not come as a surprise, you can't do this with other kinds of condition either. `||` can go *between* conditions.

Comment: why downvotes to question?

Comment: upvote, that is the exact thing I was looking for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and `matches()` to solve your problem :

```
if (textString.matches(".*_(xyz|pqr|abc)$")) {
   // do something
}
```

details :

- `.*` matches one or more character
- `_(xyz|pqr|abc)$` ends with `_` and one of the three `xyz` or `pqr` or `abc`